# Link previewing of URL PHP/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I found this article https://www.ajaxtown.com/article/facebook-type-link-preview which demonstrated on how to get a link preview which i found easy to understand and adapt.

However when i try to run it on my server i get noting back from the supplied script and the response is scrambled were as the demo on the website itself, all hunky dory works.

I know cross-site scripting is a no no but how does someone access a website and scrape back data to do something such as link previewing.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is too late, but for future visitor, i'm posting this. It is easy and fully independent. Please visit this link https://github.com/mahfuzak08/url2preview

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server, you're better off using local proxy in whatever language your server supports. Good example of such solution can be found at [AJAX Cross Origin](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com)